# how to write data in SD Card

Tags: android, android-sdcard

my application is contact list and i want to store my contact data in sd card
but how can i store data in sd card, or if i will use database then how i want to store it or using simple file than how i want to store it

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to store a simple file to the SD card, you can do it like so:

```
File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); // get a handle to the SD card
File myFile = new File(sdCard, "test"); // get a file handle so a single file
```

Now you can use a `BufferedWriter`, for example, or any other Java method of writing to that new file.

Your app should have the permission to write to the SD card, of course, by adding `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

By convention, all your application data should be stored in the following directory on the SD card: `Android/data/your.package.name/files/`

Also note that you should explicitly check whether a SD card actually exists or if its writable, and so on. See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) for a documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the path using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` and then open a file using that path.

You may have to have the following permission set:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Store contact data into device sdcard using below code.

VCardActivity.java:-

```
public class VCardActivity extends Activity {
      Cursor cursor;
      ArrayList<String> vCard;
      String vfile;
      static Context mContext;

      /** Called when the activity is first created. */
      @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            mContext = VCardActivity.this;
            getVCF();
      }

      public static void getVCF() {
            final String vfile = "Contacts.vcf";
            Cursor phones = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                                  null, null, null);
            phones.moveToFirst();
            for (int i = 0; i < phones.getCount(); i++) {
                   String lookupKey = phones.getString(phones
                           .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY));
                   Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(
                   ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_VCARD_URI,
                                                 lookupKey);
                   AssetFileDescriptor fd;
                   try {
                           fd = mContext.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
                           FileInputStream fis = fd.createInputStream();
                           byte[] buf = new byte[(int) fd.getDeclaredLength()];
                           fis.read(buf);
                           String VCard = new String(buf);
                           String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                                    .toString() + File.separator + vfile;
                           FileOutputStream mFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(path,
                                     true);
                           mFileOutputStream.write(VCard.toString().getBytes());
                           phones.moveToNext();
                           Log.d("Vcard", VCard);
                   } catch (Exception e1) {
                           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                           e1.printStackTrace();
                   }
            }
      }
}
```

and see below link for more information.

[Export Contacts as a VCF file](http://androidcodeexamples.blogspot.in/2012/06/export-contacts-as-vcf-file-in-android.html)

and give below permission into your androidmanifest.xml file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```